# UWP remote debugging error DEP4300 - Could not generate the root folder for app package

Tags: uwp, remote-debugging

I try to deploy an UWP application on a Windows 10 tablet. The remote debugger is correctly installed on the remote machine and the connection is accepted by it.
But when I deploy app from my PC, I get this error:

> DEP4300 : Could not generate the root folder for app package packageName|VS.Debug_x86.Username|CN=123456AA-AAAA-1111-2222-111111111111|packageNameVS.Debug_x86.Username with base layout folder of C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles. Caractères non conformes dans le chemin d'accès.

(I replaced values)

Note that I can deploy this app on my local machine and my Windows mobile device (by USB).

Comment: I tried to deploy this app to an other remote machine (a Windows 10 PC) and I have the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is struggling with this error message when deploying to Windows 10 IOT Core on a Raspberry Pi, here's my fix. This may apply to other Universal Windows devices, though I can't say for sure.

I started getting this error when deploying to a Raspberry Pi after upgrading Visual Studio 2015 Pro to the latest update. I followed the suggestion of updating the remote debugger tools with no success. After some troubleshooting and trial and error I learned that the issue was my Raspberry Pi itself. The Pi was running an older operating system (an older Windows 10 IOT Core build) that didn't work with the new deployment method being used by my updated development environment and remote debugger tools.

Using the Windows 10 IoT Dashboard, I flashed my SD card with the latest operating system, put the card back in the Pi, and now my deployments & debugging are working as expected.

Hope this helps somebody else!  :-)

Comment: Were you using de pi2 or pi3? I'm tried this approach with the pi3 and Windows IoT core build 14376, but still get the error when deploying.

Comment: @TomKuijsten In my case, I upgraded my Pi 2 to the latest version (build 10586) to get it working with VS 2015 Pro. I don't know what build version the pi was on before, but it was probably at least a year old.

I have a Pi 3 at home, but I'm running that with VS 2015 Community Edition and didn't have any problems there.

Answer (score 25):

This can happen after installing Update 3 of Visual Studio 2015. [Update the remote debugger tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-remote-tools) as well to fix it.

Thanks to [Tommy Wendelborg for his comment](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/06/27/visual-studio-2015-update-3-and-net-core-1-0-available-now/) that led me to this solution.

Comment: I tried reinstalling, repairing and installing vs2015 on 3 different PCs and still getting the error... I've checked google a lot but didn't find any working advice. I can see the debugger connecting to the remote device but then the error pops up.

Comment: I tried this with ARM but there isn't an update to those remote tools, so I guess its still broken there.

Comment: @GavinPickin ...I had to upgrade the OS on my ARM device (Raspberry Pi) to get it to work with the new Visual Studio and debugger tools.

Comment: @P.Stresow Like you I set up a new virtual machine with a fresh visual studio install and kept getting the error. Eventually discovered I had to update my device (Raspberry Pi in my case) to get the error to go away and get deployment/debugging to work.

Comment: I have a surface RT, so can't really update that. I poked the remote tools team, hoping they update that. I just side loaded the app instead.

Comment: I ran into this problem and it took so long to fix. The link that Tommy Wendelborg posted in the comment section of the blog immediately redirects you to a different page now. The page is [Visual Studio Downloads](https://beta.visualstudio.com/downloads/). Scroll down to the Latest Releases search box and search for Remote Tools. You should be given the Remote Tools Update 3 download. I could not find that download via any search engine for some strange reason. Only that one search on that one page. Thankfully that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the correct working link to update the debugging tools on the destination device for now until Microsoft changes or breaks it again: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615470&clcid=0x409